# Replicating behavior of the Python string.split() function in Qt

Tags: python, regex, string, qt, split

I'm currently trying to exactly replicate the behavior of the Python split() function (the default version, without any arguments) in Qt.

I have been told that the default delimiter is any number of CR/LF/TAB symbols, therefore I tried using the following:

```
s_body.split(QRegExp("[\r\n\t ]+"), QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

However, this does not replicate its behavior precisely.

If I run this on approximately 4 megabytes worth of text, and count the number of unique words, i get 133293. However, if I do the same using the Python function, the result becomes 133367 - therefore there is still something amiss.

Any feedback on how to fix this would be greatly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Python is *not* skipping empty strings, and they are accounting for the difference. If you want your function to mimic's Python functionality, you can choose to include empty strings, or if you want to get the behavior you've implemented, you can write `s_body.split()` in Python; with no arguments, it strips all whitespace between non-whitespace characters, which means you get no empty strings back.

Comment: I attempted to do as you said and keep empty parts. However, this did not work. I also tried [\v\f\r\t\n ]+ as a delimiter. This still did not yield precise results for most of the files I tested this on (however, the percentage of files where it got it right did increase slightly with that regexp.

Answer (score 0):

With a unicode string, python's `split()` will, quite naturally, split on the set of *all unicode whitespace characters*, not just the feeble ascii set:

```
>>> s = '\t_\n_\x0b_\x0c_\r_ _\x85_\xa0_\u1680_\u2000_\u2001_\u2002_\u2003_\u2004_\u2005_\u2006_\u2007_\u2008_\u2009_\u200a_\u2028_\u2029_\u202f_\u205f_\u3000_'
>>> len(s)
50
>>> len(s.split())
25
>>> ''.join(s.split())
'_________________________'
```

Now let's see what Qt does (using PyQt4):

```
>>> qs = QString(s)
>>> r = qs.split(QRegExp('\\s+'), QString.SkipEmptyParts)
>>> r.count()
24
>>> str(r.join(''))
'______\x85___________________'
```

So, almost there, but for some reason `U+0085 NEL (Next Line)` is not recognzed as whitespace in Qt4 - but that's easily remedied:

```
>>> r = qs.split(QRegExp('[\\s\x85]+'), QString.SkipEmptyParts)
>>> r.count()
25
>>> str(r.join(''))
'_________________________'
```